# Electric Dryer Wiring

Tags: electrical, dryer

I am moving laundry about 40' from current location.
I want to tie in to the existing dryer wiring which is 10 gauge.
Can I use 10 gauge wire to run 40' or should I use 8 gauge.

Comment: How long is the existing run? 40' of #10 copper @ 30 amp would have a voltage drop of ~2.9 volts, which is only 1.2% of 240 volts.  So you'll have to add that to the voltage drop of the existing run, to determine if you're within acceptable power quality tolerances.

Comment: I would just add that the joints that you make to extend the circuit need to be in a junction box that remains accessible after you are done. You can NOT bury the joints under the drywall or floor. If you have a basement where the wires feed from, then that is where the joints should be made in an electrical  junction box.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the existing run is under 40' the additional length of 40' will not be a problem.  It is however very important to make sure the connections between the old run and the new are tight.